# Create table in snowflake - Syntax

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a table and insert rows into it. But it keeps giving me this syntax error.
ERROR : SQL compilation error: syntax error line 3 at position 1 unexpected 'EventName'. syntax

Any help would be appreciated.

```
create or replace table pd_press_dev._raz.ID (
     EventTypeID int
     EventName,
     EventDescription,
     EventCategoryName,
     SystemName,
     RecordChecksum,
     RecordAppend,
     RecordUpdate);
     
    INSERT INTO pd_press_dev._raz.ID 
    (-1,'NO_EVENT_TYPE','Event Type Not Defined','NO_EVENT_CATEGORY','INSITE','-770355665','0.00218634259259259','0.00218634259259259');
```

Comment: This question is not related to #snowflake-schema so will remove that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to type those columns, and you are missing a comma after the int of EnventTypeID

```
create or replace table pd_press_dev._raz.ID (
     EventTypeID int,
     EventName text,
     EventDescription text,
     EventCategoryName text,
     SystemName text,
     RecordChecksum text,
     RecordAppend text,
     RecordUpdate text);
```

and your insert needs a VALUES keyword:

```
INSERT INTO pd_press_dev._raz.ID values
    (-1, 'NO_EVENT_TYPE', 'Event Type Not Defined', 'NO_EVENT_CATEGORY', 
       'INSITE', '-770355665', '0.00218634259259259', '0.00218634259259259');
```

```
SELECT * FROM ID;
```

| EVENTTYPEID | EVENTNAME | EVENTDESCRIPTION | EVENTCATEGORYNAME | SYSTEMNAME | RECORDCHECKSUM | RECORDAPPEND | RECORDUPDATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -1 | NO_EVENT_TYPE | Event Type Not Defined | NO_EVENT_CATEGORY | INSITE | -770355665 | 0.00218634259259259 | 0.00218634259259259 |